# ActiveMQConnectionFactory in Python

Tags: java, python, push-notification, activemq-classic

I have some code in Java that uses the class `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` to get notification messages from a push service. What's the Python alternative of that class?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure there is an exact alternative for ActiveMQConnectionFactory, for using python to consume/produce messages i use stomp. 
See:
http://activemq.apache.org/cross-language-clients.html

You can find code example in the answer here:
[Python JMS Stomp client and Apache ActiveMQ - Listener does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598375/python-jms-stomp-client-and-apache-activemq-listener-does-not-work)